# post() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given) - flask.ext.resful

Tags: python, rest, python-2.7, flask

I want to upload a file along with other parameters using flask.ext.restful:

```
from flask.ext import restful

class Test1(restful.Resource):
    def post(self, arg1, arg2, file_name):
        f = request.files['files']
        f.save(f.filename + arg1 + arg2)
        return 'good!'

api.add_resource(Test1, '/test123')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And then I call it as

```
curl -F "arg1=arg1_test" -F "arg2=arg2_test" -F "files=@some_file_name.txt" http://127.0.0.1:5000/test123
```

And I get "`TypeError: post() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)`"

Comment: Did you also try `curl -F "arg1=arg1_test" "arg2=arg2_test" "files=@some_file_name.txt" http://127.0.0.1:5000/test123`?